# How to create many to many relationship in prisma2

Tags: mysql, graphql, prisma2

I am using Prisma2+GraphQL and I would like to write schema.prisma

this is my code below

```
model Message {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  text String
  from User
  to User
  room Room
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  User User @relation("from", fields:[from], references:[id])
  User User @relation("to", fields:[to], references:[id])
}
```

and I got an error like **Field "User" is already defined on model "Message".**

My Question is How can I relate from & to columns to User in prisma2?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way to do the relation between `User` and `Messages`.

```
model User {
  id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String
  fromMessages Message[] @relation("fromUser")
  toMessages   Message[] @relation("toUser")
}

model Message {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  text      String
  fromId    Int
  toId      Int
  from      User     @relation("fromUser", fields: [fromId], references: [id])
  to        User     @relation("toUser", fields: [toId], references: [id])
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}
```